# Where to get Subscription Id

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

I want to get Auto renew subscription detail for that i can follow this official **[DOCUMENT](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get)**:

In this document first step is Authorization. and i complete all steps and i get **`refresh_token`** AND **`access_token`**.

Now main part is there is one API to get renew subscription detail:
API: https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/products/productId/tokens/token

In this api there is three data required:

1. PackageName - Which i add from AndroidManifest.xml
2. SubscriptionId : Where to i get Subscription ID?
3. Token : Which i can get from Authorization steps.

Main problem is **Where to i get subscription ID**. Is Product Id is Subscription ID or What??

If SubscriptionId is ProductId then my API not working. API response is:

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid",
            "message": "Invalid Value"
        }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid Value"
}
}
```

Anyone have solution? or information about Subscription ID?

Answer (score 0):

**subscription ID** is another term for SKU. You may also see it listed as **product ID**. They are the ID that you entered in the [Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com) when you first listed your products

`https://play.google.com >> [choose an app] >> Store presence >> In-app products >> subscriptions >> Name & ID`

The ID that you see there is the subscription ID.

Another way to find your SKU (aka subscription ID, product ID), is through `SkuDetails#getSku()` on the list of SkuDetails you get from `querySkuDetailsAsync(params)` in your Android client.

**update with javascript/typescript snippet**

```
async function getSubscriptionPurchaseFromPlay(sku: string, purchaseToken: string) {
    const params = {
        packageName: PACKAGE_NAME,
        subscriptionId: sku,
        token: purchaseToken
    };
    const response = await playDeveloperApi.purchases.subscriptions.get(params);
    console.log("getSubsPurchaseFromPlay response:: ", response);
    return response.data;
}
```

You must use the SKU in all places where you are requested to provide productId or subscriptionId. For example:

- https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/products/productId/tokens/token
- https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token

Comment: I already follow this path `https://play.google.com >> [choose an app] >> Store presence >> In-app products >> subscriptions >> Name & ID` but there define as a product Id.

Comment: Yes the product ID is what you need to set as the subscriptionId in the url. It should work

Comment: additing a javascript/typescript snippet.